# Toggle navbar item only on lower width jQuery

Tags: jquery

In my case i have simple header menu in which 2 of the `li` tags has submenu. I want to trigger `toggleClass` only when the screen width is lower than `992px`.
Tried with `if($(window).width() > 992)` but without result.

```
function fetchMenu(e) {
    var $elem = $('#'+e.id);
    var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sub-menu');
    $sub_menu.toggleClass('visible-class');
    return false;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

I did it! Don't know is it the right way but it is working for me :)

```
$(function () {
    $('.menu-item-custom').on('click', function () {
       if($(window).width() < 992){
           var $elem = $(this);
           var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sub-menu');
           $sub_menu.toggleClass('visible-class');
           return false;
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with

```
$(window).resize(function(){
     if (screen.width < 922) {
     //your function here
    }
    else {

      // another function here
    }
        });
```

you also need to use  `if (screen.width < 922)`when the document load to detect if the screen size is less then 922 when the document load

Comment: `Screen.width` is returning 1920 always. Guess it is returning always the width of my monitor but and when i decide to resize the browser it returns me 1920 again :) Will update the post to see how i did it.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it with css

`@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    // add your class here
}`

Comment: he didnt tag CSS he is looking for a Jquery solution

Comment: "Or" .. it's an option